# Add Favicon to text/plain response

Tags: html, http, server, http-headers

When a user requests my service I'd like to respond with Content-Type text/plain, but I'd also like to send the favicon with it.

Is there a way with HTTP/1.1 to send a favicon when using text/plain?

Answer (score 2):

Alternative answer, while Slaks is correct, it's also possible to use a HTTP Link header instead of a HTML `<link>` element.

```
Link: </favicon.ico>; rel="icon"
```

Comment: hmmm - I've attempted this and no luck

Comment: which browser? No luck doesn't help that much.

Comment: Looking for an all browser solution rather than one - attempted in chrome n firefox

Answer (score 1):

you need to tell the server ( http/https ?) that respond an icon/image file when client requests `/favicon.ico`, since your question is broad, i am considering the case of configuring `nginx`, config file will be like,

```
server{
 server_name mydomain_name;
 location /favicon.ico {
      alias /path/to/ico/file;
 }
}
```

also note that as @Evert's answer it is good to return a response header from application server with response header with,

```
Link: </favicon.ico>; rel="icon" # header key Link is set value from application response code
```

If you meant case of a website/application with an HTML output on browser, most browser is compatible with `<link>` syntax, so between `<head>` add this code

```
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="/path/to/icon/image"/>
</head>
```

if you use above code in html all/first requested page, browser will set the website icon as png/jpg image from `href`.

Answer (score 0):

No.

However, most browsers will try `/favicon.ico` if you don't have relevant tags.

Comment: could you elaborate on the relevant tags?

Comment: Sorry; I meant if you _don't_ have relevant tags (which you can't since you aren't serving HTML).